# What is the difference between using an actuator/shutdown vs SIGTERM to gracefully terminate a Spring application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've noticed discrepancies in behavior between SIGTERM-ing my application (via kill) and running actuator/shutdown, but I'm having trouble seeing why they are different.

Comment: Can you detail the behavior differences between shutting down by means of calling an actuator and by beans of sending a SIGTERM?

Comment: Both are being run from command line, with one being a java file that sends the POST request to https://localhost.com:5019/actuator/shutdown (response is the expected{message: shutting down bye}) and one just being kill [pid of application].

In terms of behavior, the shutdown command completes but the process linked to the PID doesn't actually go down. Yes the endpoints are exposed, and yes the port numbers match.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. In my @PreDestroy methods, I didn't clean up certain threads which remained active as Spring went down due to them not being managed by Spring.

So the difference is that Spring's Actuator shutdown will not clean up threads not managed by Spring, whereas a SIGTERM will.